# error Message of "httpMessageNotReadableException" when converting JSON request python

Tags: python, json, request

i am having a problem with a rest API request in a json format which cannot be converted. The request code looks like this:

```
headers = {"content-type": "application/json","username": "xxx" , "password": "xxx" , "domain": "xxx" }

r = requests.post("https://psepmlan1:8446/sepm/api/v1/identity/authenticate",headers=headers,verify=False)

print r.content
```

The error that I am getting looks like this:

```
{"errorCode":"500","errorMessage":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"}
```

i tried to read some issues regarding to this error and i understood that it is about the way you passing the json request and yet, i was not able to send a proper request.

any suggestions?

best regards

Comment: as an example of a post request of the system they gave this one:  POST /sepm/api/v1/identity/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
"username" : "admin",
"password" : "password",
"domain" : ""
}

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have 'a.json'. Please do these while post request.

```
json_data=open('a.json', 'r')

values = json.load(json_data)

requests.post(url = url, data = json.dumps(values), headers = header )
```

This will work. I got the same error as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data as json in the request body, not in the request headers:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> data = {'user': 'Foo', 'password': 'bar', 'domain': ''}
>>> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
>>> response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

# httpbin.org/post is a service that accepts a POST request and returns 
# the details of the request as its response
>>> response.json()

{'args': {}, 'data': '{"user": "Foo", "password": "bar", "domain": ""}', 'files': {}, 'form': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '48', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.12.4'}, 'json': {'domain': '', 'password': 'bar', 'user': 'Foo'}, 'origin': '82.36.117.40', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```